# How to transfer knowledge of a code performance to its dual?

Tags: coding-theory

Suppose I have a binary linear block code $C$. If I know it's weight distribution, the MacWilliams identity will give the weight distribution of its dual $C^\perp$. Now suppose I have some other important data on $C$, in particular, let's say I have its minimum distance $d_{min}$, bit error probability $P_b$ and codeworde error probability, $P_w$; the last two for example would be functions of signal to noise ratio for an AWGN channel. How do I get $d_{min}(C^\perp)$,$P_b(C^\perp)$, $P_w(C^\perp)$ from  $d_{min}(C)$,$P_b(C)$, $P_w(C)$?

Comment: This would be nice to have, but I somehow doubt it is possible. That is just a hunch though and it may be wrong. After all, the BER & BLER curves have infinitely points, so, thinking that the curve contains an awful lot of information about the code, may be it is possible to fully recover a code from its BER-curve!

Comment: the dual code is completely defined by the original code so in principle everything about it (include BER/BLER) can be derived from the original code. Many decoders actually perform the calculations in the dual code space...Fourier transforms (for finite fields) are used to go back and forth between the two; that's why I thought there might have been work done in moving results from one domain to the other.